# CDF of $V_i=\max{(aY_{i-1},Y_i)}, \forall i=2,...,n ; V_1=Y_1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables with Frechét's distribution, i.e. $F_X(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}},x>0$. Let $M_n=\max{(X_1,...,X_n)}$.

- Find the CDF of $M_n$ and $\frac{M_n}{n}$.

$\rightarrow F_{M_n}(m_n)=\mathbb{P}(M_n\leq m_n)=e^{-\frac{n}{m_n}}$ and $F_{\frac{M_n}{n}}(m_n)=\mathbb{P}(M_n\leq n m_n)=e^{-\frac{1}{m_n}}$

Let $Y_0,Y_1,Y_2,...$ a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables with $F_Y(y)=e^{-\frac{1}{y(a+1)}},y>0,a \in [0,1]$. Let $V_i$ a random process such that $V_1=Y_1$ and $V_i=\max{(aY_{i-1},Y_i)}, \forall i=2,...,n$.

- Find the CDF of $V_i$ and $\frac{M_{n}^{*}}{n}$, where $M_{n}^{*}=\max{(V_1,...,V_n)}$.

I'm stuck on the second point. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the role of $Y_0$? because you don't use $Y_0$ in your problem

Comment: @annie_lee All I did was write out the full text. It's not specified the role of $Y_0$.

Comment: What is your work on part 2?  If you ignore $Y_0$ can you write out $\max[V_1, ..., V_n]$ as a max over a collection of random variables that invole $Y_i$?